# Biztalk flat file disassembler

Tags: biztalk

Can anyone tell me.....

When a `.txt` file is picked up in a pipeline with a flat file disassembler, if the correct schema is used in the pipeline does the `.txt` file come out the other end of the pipeline as `xml` or is something else needed to get to this stage?

I'm kind of new to Biztalk so apologies if this is worded wrongly or not making much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is basically how it works yes. Actually the end result is an xml message delivered from the pipeline into the BizTalk message box database. From this point other processes can pick up the message and process it.